# Not able to find data sheet and header files for Beaglebone Black processor(AM3358BZCZ100)

Tags: beagleboneblack

I want to start working on BeagleBone Black Rev C. 
This board has AM3358BZCZ100 processor.

I am looking for data sheet for this processor, but not able to find it anywhere in internet.
Can you please help me getting this?

I need,
(1) Data sheet for AM3358BZCZ100.
(2) Header files for AM3358BZCZ100 to program in C.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The best place for looking for information is on Texas Instrument web site, on the [AM3358 page](http://www.ti.com/product/am3358). The "Sample&Buy" tab lists the different available part numbers, including the AM3358BZCZ100.

The AM3358 is am member of the AM335x family, and there is a description of the differences between members on the AM3358 page.

You will need the AM335x Sitara Processors Technical Reference Manual (Rev. K) as well, there is a link to it on the AM3358 page.

If you want to program in C on bare metal, you will probably find the Starterware for AM335X extremely useful.
You can download it from the "Tools&Software" tab of the AM3358 page.

Since the AM3358 is a Cortex-A8, you may want to download the "ARM® Architecture Reference Manual ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition", as well as the "Cortex™-A8 Revision: r3p2 Technical Reference Manual" from ARM web site.